# Very simple segmentation fault error c++

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

I am unexperienced in c++ and am encountering a basic segmentation fault error which I don't know how to fix. I create a dynamic 2d array and then change the values of that array. The example in case is the following code:

```
string** fishdata = new string*[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    fishdata[i] = new string[6];

fishdata[currentfish][count] += "example";
```

The very last line of this code returns a segmentation fault error

Comment: Why on earth you are using `new` here? Also `'example'` isn't a string literal.

Comment: Im not sure what should I be using?

Comment: It appears that what you're actually looking for is `std::vector<std::string>`. And I assume it's a typo, but single quotes are for character literals; use double quotes for string literals. If your goal is to learn C++, make sure you're learning from a book about C++, not one written about C!

Comment: sorry example should've been a string

Comment: I agree with @Cody, `std::vector<std::string>>` or `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>`  seems what you're looking for.

Comment: What are the values of `currentfish` and `count` ?

Comment: Your code is ugly but works as is; see demo <http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cd43e2c61c2c66c>. Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: @YSC - how can you tell that it works when the value of two variables are unknown?

Comment: @4386427 No MCVE, I can fill missing data with whatever I want. Of course the values of the two variables matters; but I don't care: no MCVE ;)

Comment: Very sorry to waste everyones time it was a dumb fix with that count was a number bigger than 5... I'm an idiot

Comment: @BernardoRodriguez - you're not an idiot because you make a programming mistake - we all do :-) But the next time you post a question please try to include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many people said in the comments it was a dumb mistake about the value of the variable count, which was larger than 5 (the size of the second dimension of the array).